# While installing Informatica gretting Error:Command to create the domain failed

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

While Installing Informatica i am getting this ERROR....

The command to create the domain failed.
 Select OK to correct the domain information and try the command again.
 Select Continue to continue the installation without creating the domain.
 You can run the command to create the domain after installation.
 Review the log files for more information.

Informatica_9.0.1_Services_HotFix2.log   [LOG FILES SAY'S]

```
Domain name: : Domain_SONY 
Node host name: : SONY 
Node name: : node01_SONY 
Node port number: : 6005 
NODE_ADDRESS : SONY:6005
LOGS_DIRECTORY : C:\Informatica\9.0.1\isp\logs 
BACKUP_DIRECTORY : C:\Informatica\9.0.1\server\infa_shared\Backup 
DOMAIN_USER : Administrator 
  DOMAIN_PSSWD : ***** 
    NODEOPTIONS_XML : C:\Informatica\9.0.1\isp\bin\nodeoptions.xml
```

Exit Code : -1

OutPut : [ICMD_10033] Command [defineDomain] failed with error 
[[INFASETUP_10002} Cannot create domain, operation failed with error:
 [INFASETUP_10000] C:\Informatica\9.0.1\tomcat\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the file specified).].
Error :

```
 I Think i need to fix server.xml file but HOW?
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED..

Answer (score 0):

I could be too late to answer this. 
Usually this error would occur when the installer file was not unzipped properly. Try using winzip to unzip the installer files and proceed with the installation.

Reference: Informatica KB Article - 151835